# How do we use nested if else with #define preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

```cpp
#define len(a) if (a == 8)   1       \
               else if (a == 3) 0    \
               else -1
```

this code is just an example how do we use nested if else.
I don't want to use ternary operator as in that case i can't use else if statement.

Comment: Use a function.

Comment: Why do you want to use the preprocessor for this?

Comment: I'd highly appreciate it if you'd do it in my competitor's code base.

Comment: you can also nest the conditional operator.

Comment: The question is unclear. You ask how to use nested if else, and you show how you used nested if else. So, what is the question?

Comment: there is a `)` too much, otherwise I dont see the problem with this code (apart from using a macro of course)

Comment: @eer it obviously doesn't work. an if-else chain cannot evaluate to a value like `1` or `0`.

Comment: C and C++ don't have if expressions, so the conditional operator is the best you're going get as an inline expression.

Comment: I just want to learn how to do this using pre-processors like we can easily use do this using ternary operator but i want to know any other way to use nested if else with #define...

Comment: Avoid using `#define` because it can be overwritten and the compiler will not tell you. Unless you set a version with #define. The C++ language does not handle #define, a tool does, so when something causes an error the compiler cannot help you.

Comment: @udi the preprocessor is not the correct tool to use here. That's why we call it 'abuse'

Comment: *I just want to learn how to do this using pre-processors* `#define len(a) [](int x) -> int { if (x == 8) return 1; if (x == 3) return 0; return -1; }(a)`  Now that you have learned how to do it, I also hope that you have learned not to do it.

Comment: Pick one tag, C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int len(const int a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 8: return 1;
        case 3: return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I haven't programmed in C++ forever, I think I had `constexpr` mixed up with `inline`.

Comment: as I understand it has to be both valid C & C++

Comment: Note that `__attribute__((always_inline))` is non-standard and does not work in all compilers.

Answer (score 6):

Don't abuse the preprocessor. Use a real function:

```
constexpr auto len(int const a) {
    if (a == 8) return 1;
    if (a == 3) return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Legend, great answer. Constexpr's will precompile correct? But raise an error if any value fails or changes? So very similar to a preprocessor. Does `auto` as the keyword also have to be used?

Comment: @Ray if the provided argument is a constant expression, the result will be calculated at compile time as well. If it's not, the result isn't either.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert, It _can be_, but to force it to be done at compile time, you need to use the result in a context that requires a constant expression.

Comment: @chr yes, you're right. I imagine most compilers will do that optimization anyway. And even if the argument is not constexpr, it's likely to be inlined. So this exactly like preprocessing, but much more convenient to write/use/maintain.

Comment: it is only C++. will not compile as C

Comment: @P__J__ I def had inline mixed up with constexpr, but none the less I still think these answers are great. Don't use a #define unless it is some work requirement some boss is demanding.

Comment: @P__J__ you could have a macro defined `#ifndef __cplusplus #define constexpr #endif`. So you can't tell if it's valid C or not.

Comment: using this logic you can write in pascal between #ifdef __PASCAL__

Comment: @P__J__ what if someone defines `PASCAL`? The C standard guarantees that the `__cplusplus` macro will not be defined in a well-defined C program. And since making this valid C is as trivial as removing the `constexpr` I don't see the point of any of these. Most compilers will inline and do compile-time calculations in all contexts that are suitable for the C language, and you have no other option for the C++ constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use GNU extensions and insist on a macro with `if`-`else` branching, you can use [compound statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs):

```
#define len(a) ({                 \
    int _res = -1;                \
    if ((a) == 8) _res = 1;       \
    else if ((a) == 3) _res = 0;  \
    (_res); })
```

This works both in C and C++. Unfortunately, such compound statements cannot be used in constant expressions.

Comment: So this is like [using a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247599/how-do-we-use-nested-if-else-with-define-preprocessor/62247667?noredirect=1#comment110090806_62247599), but non-portable?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert, not fully equivalent. In that lambda, `a` is evaluated just once, here it can be evaluated twice. This can easily be fixed. And there are no lamdas in C.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "I don't want to use ternary operator as in that case i can't use else if statement" -- well, yes, you can't use `else if` in a ternary operator. But you can use another ternary operator:

```
int x = a == 8 ? 1
    : a == 3 ? 0
    : -1;
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no issue in writing nested or not `if` statements in a macro, or at least no more issues than usual when you try to wrap statements in macros. But note that I used **statement**, there is no such thing as an `if` expression in either C or C++ excepted the ternary operator you don't want to use.

So if you want nested `if`s statements in a macro, you can do something like

```
#define stmt(c1, c2) \
   if (c1) \
      do_1(); \
   else if (c2) \
      do_2(); \
   else \
      do_3()
```

(note that the way to escape end of lines is with `\` and not with `/`). If you want an expression, you'll have either to use the ternary operator or a function as showed in other answers. Well, even if you need statements, I'd suggest to use a function instead of a macro.

Comment: I cant find any reason of doing it except to make code hard to debug and hard to read

Comment: @AProgrammer All the other answers covered this. This is not practical.

Comment: @P__J__ you commented while I was adding the fact that even for statements I'd recommend a function.

Comment: @AProgrammer  always suggest waiting to finish your complete answer, before submitting it. That way this issue will be avoided in the future.